# Android - Showing value taken from SQLite db to a TextView

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

I want to get the `String` taken from SQLite db and write it into a textview.

Here's the code for my `MainClass` which tries to call the value from SQLite db :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ChosenSlotDAO chosenSlotDAO = new ChosenSlotDAO(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        //String hoho = "Hohoho";

        chosenSlotDAO.open();
        TextView chosenSlotView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chosenSlotTView);

        String slots = chosenSlotDAO.getSlot();
        chosenSlotDAO.createSlot(slots);

        if(slots == null)
        {
            chosenSlotView.setText("You have not parked");
        }
        else
        {
            chosenSlotView.setText(slots);
        }

        chosenSlotDAO.close();
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do here is to automatically show user's parking location.

I have this snippet in my MainMap class which comes after tapping NFC at the entrance of the parking slot :

```
chosenSlotDAO.open();
chosenSlotDAO.dropTable();
chosenSlotDAO.close();
```

So basically whenever user taps the entrance NFC the table is dropped to show that user isn't parked(this is a software prototype, it is supposed to be exit NFC, but as exit is not in the scope of my application development, as a convenience, I placed the code in entrance).

This is my `dropTable()` code :

```
public void dropTable() {
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ChosenSlotDatabaseHandler.TABLE_CHOSEN_PARKING_SLOT);
}
```

Does the drop table mess with the value inside the textview?

If no, then what could be wrong?

Comment: **Just a suggestion:** If the chosenSlotDAO is the object that implements the DAO pattern, you are using it in the wrong way: the DAO object should provide an abstract interface to the database for retrieving data. So should provide methods like: `getSlot(id)` or `getAllSlot()` or `deleteSlot(Slot s)` and so on.

Comment: The answer is a `NO`.

Comment: Hahaha, I forgot to add another parameter in my question. Ah, I have it in my `ChosenParkingSlot`, then I should add it and use it inside the main class?